# Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting in my code

Tags: php

I am new in Php I have to send resume using phpmailer. I found error as "Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting". Plz need change in code. I am using phpmailer in my code. It works when i am doing first time but now this code will gives error.

```
<?php 

include('header.php');
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$message='';

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
   $path='upload/'.$_FILES["resume"]["name"];
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $path);

   $mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'xyz01@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypasswordgoeshere';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From=$_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName=$_POST['name'];
$mail->setFrom($_POST['email']);
$mail->addAddress('xyz01@gmail.com'); 

$mail->AddCC($_POST['name'],$_POST['email']);

$mail->WordWrap=50;

$mail->AddAttachment($path);

$mail->Subject='application for job';
    // Add a recipient
              // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

//$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mail->Body    = $_POST['message'];
$mail->AltBody = $_POST['message'];



if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo '<script>alert("Message could not be sent.")</script>';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("Message has been sent");

        window.location.href="career.php";
    </script>';

}


}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you changed the settings in your gmail security by changing your less secure app access and turn it on

Answer (score -1):

Remove or comment `$mail->isSMTP();` from code and try again! or also check your username and password in code.

Comment: This is not the solution by doing this It will just send the email with the default mail() function.